# How to trigger a method in foreground when internet is available in UWP?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp

I know we can create a background trigger when the internet is available. But is there a method to trigger a call when the internet becomes available in the foreground app?

Currently I'm polling every few minutes to check if the internet is available but this is not so efficient.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to trigger a `UI` method or just a business logic in the foreground project ? You currently create a windows run-time component project for the background task right ?

Comment: Just the business logic. I don't want this to execute in the background, just   when the app is active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged += NetworkInformation_NetworkStatusChanged;
```

[MSDN NetworkInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! Looks like this is what I need!